# If $Y_n \overset{d}\to Y$, $Z_n \overset{d}\to Z$ and $Y\perp Z$ then $(Y_n, Z_n) \overset{d}\to (Y,Z)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

## Setup

Assume that the random variable sequence $\{Y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ tends in distribution to $Y$, the random variable sequence $\{Z_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ tends in distribution to $Z$, and $Y$ and $Z$ are independent. Also, the following limits hold.
$$
P(Y_n > y, Z_n >z) \to P(Y>y)\cdot P(Z>z).
$$

## Question

Then, $(Y_n, Z_n)\overset{d}{\to}(Y, Z)$ holds. I want to show this.

## What I think

From the definition of convergence in distribution, it is sufficient to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(Y_n\leq y, Z_n\leq z) = P(Y\leq y, Z\leq z)$.
This can be transformed as follows.
\begin{align}
1-\lim_{n\to\infty}P(Y_n\leq y, Z_n\leq z) &= 1-P(Y\leq y, Z\leq z)\\
&=P(Y>y, Z>z)
\end{align}

I am stuck with this. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Kroki I wish I could transform $1-\lim_{n\to\infty}P(Y_n\leq y, Z_n\leq z) = \lim_{n\to\infty}P(Y_n>y, Z_n>z)$, but I can't transform the left side like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left(Y_n \le y, Z_n \le z\right) &= 1 - \mathbb P\left(Y_n > y \cup Z_n > z\right)\\
&= 1 - \mathbb P\left(Y_n > y\right) - \mathbb P\left(Z_n > z\right) + \mathbb P\left(Y_n > y, Z_n > z\right)\\
&= \mathbb P\left(Y_n \le y\right) + \mathbb P \left(Z_n \le z\right) - 1 + \mathbb P\left(Y_n > y, Z_n > z\right)\to ?
\end{align}
Can you finish the proof?

Comment: How can $Y_n$ and $Z_n$ have that transformation if they are not independent?

Comment: I edit the answer to fix your problem.

Comment: I thought about your answer, but I can't find $P(Y_n>y)$.

Comment: I added a step that helps

Comment: Thank you. How does the change in the direction of the inequality sign change things?

Comment: Use the convergence of probability ofeach $Y_n$ and $Z_n$